# Preserve Polymorphism in Json string with Gson2.1 and asmx web service

Tags: android, json, polymorphism, asmx, gson

I would like to ask two questions in regard to json strings when handling `polymorphism`

- I would like to know if there's a way to include object type info in
  json string when using Gson? I need to pass this type info to my .net
  asmx web service which then should reconstruct the object of same
  type provided.
- How to get such info back form asmx web service and what are the keys used by .net to automatically detect this info? For e.g **__type** but i don't know if .net uses this when provided or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extension for Gson called RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory. It allows you to add type information to your JSON document. Get the [source here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java).

Comment: but does it automatically work fine with .NET's Json implementation? as i have tried to set **__type** manually in my Json object and it didn't work out

Comment: It should work. It allows you to use whatever string you want for "type".